# C# HttpClient PUT

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, put

For some reason my below code that used to work now consequently raises an exception:

```
public static async Task<string> HttpPut(string inUrl, string inFilePath)
    {
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                //var content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(inFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true));
                using (var content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(inFilePath, FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

                    using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, inUrl))
                    {
                        string authInfo = String.Format("{0}:{1}", Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").UserName, Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").Password);
                        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
                        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
                        req.Headers.Remove("Expect");
                        req.Headers.Add("Expect", "");
                        //req.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;

                        req.Content = content;

                        // Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

                        using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
                        {
                            //This part is specific to the setup on an Expo we're at...
                            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)
                            {
                                string redirectUrl = resp.Headers.Location.ToString();

                                if (redirectUrl.Contains("vme-store"))
                                {
                                    redirectUrl = redirectUrl.Replace("vme-store", "10.230.0.11");
                                }
                                return await HttpPut(redirectUrl, inFilePath);
                            }

                            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233067
Message=The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
Source=System
StackTrace:
     at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VizWolfInnerServer.Tools.HttpConnector.<HttpPut>d__39.MoveNext() in c:\Users\christer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VizWolfNew\VizWolfInnerServer\Tools\HttpConnector.cs:line 202
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at VizWolfInnerServer.Tools.VizAPIConnector.<VmeUploadMedia>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\Users\christer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VizWolfNew\VizWolfInnerServer\Tools\VizAPIConnector.cs:line 187
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
InnerException:
```

I'm having a very hard time finding proper documentation and examples for HttpClient, and I'm struggling with figuring out why this suddenly doesn't work (a totally similar method with StringContent instead of StreamContent works perfectly)...

It originally gets called from it's own thread, and then like this:

```
public static async void VmeUploadMedia(string inUploadLink, string inFilePath)
{
    string result = await HttpConnector.HttpPut(inUploadLink, inFilePath);
}
```

Anyone spot anything obvious?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Turns out getting the expo-guys to map their storage-name with it's IP so I could go back to my original code was the best solution. The problem I was having is something to do with AllowAutoRedirect = false. The exception occured on HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req), even if there was no redirection really going on. I'm kind of lost as to why it was even happening, but using this code everything is working now:

```
public static async Task<string> HttpPut(string inUrl, string inFilePath)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(inFilePath)))
            {
                content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

                using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, inUrl))
                {
                    string authInfo = String.Format("{0}:{1}", Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").UserName, Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").Password);
                    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
                    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
                    req.Headers.Remove("Expect");
                    req.Headers.Add("Expect", "");

                    req.Content = content;

                    // Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

                    using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
                    {
                        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to the people who were trying to help

Comment: it is alright to add you answer as a actual answer on the site and select as the correct answer. At the moment it seems like it is an unanswered question.

Comment: Good point, doing that now

Comment: Could you now not just use PutAsJsonAsync<>?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out getting the expo-guys to map their storage-name with it's IP so I could go back to my original code was the best solution. The problem I was having is something to do with AllowAutoRedirect = false. The exception occured on HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req), even if there was no redirection really going on. I'm kind of lost as to why it was even happening, but using this code everything is working now:

```
public static async Task<string> HttpPut(string inUrl, string inFilePath)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(inFilePath)))
            {
                content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

                using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, inUrl))
                {
                    string authInfo = String.Format("{0}:{1}", Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").UserName, Program.Config.MediaStorageList.Find(o => o.Name == "Viz Media Engine Test").Password);
                    authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
                    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authInfo);
                    req.Headers.Remove("Expect");
                    req.Headers.Add("Expect", "");

                    req.Content = content;

                    // Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

                    using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
                    {
                        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                        return await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to the people who were trying to help

Answer (score 1):

```
using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
```

It seems that this line will create a new context for that execution, hence a new thread context, maybe you cannot do that, because you will share the lock of the FileStream.

Comment: There's no way around grabbing the response though is there?

If you're thinking about the using-part, I actually threw that on there after I started getting that exception to try to make sure I disposed of everything

Comment: If you think about that, this code is pretty much useless the way you're using it, because you use an async function but then you still block the execution, I would understand if you're using a callback which is not the case.

Comment: If I've understood correctly the await-statements sends control back to the caller while working, it was an attempt at making sure there was no way the upload would block anything on the server. I'm not sure I've understood everything about it correctly though, I'm very much still a rookie. As to your update, yeah I think I'll have to switch to httpwebresponse/request instead of HttpClient if I don't figure it out soon. I'm not sure how easy Http PUT is there though?

Comment: `using (HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.SendAsync(req))`

It seems that this line will create a new context for that execution, hence a new thread context, maybe you cannot do that.


Can I use something like [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx for this? Or is my thinking way off for this entire thing when it comes to threads and async

Comment: Did you try to replace thus code with the one I provided in the "update" just to make sure the problem is not coming from here?

Comment: Actually the code I provided is from another class, so forget it. I created a mock site to test your code against it and was able to get the same exception. When creating a FileStream the default FileAccess is ReadWrite, so you need to use this contructor instead:FileStream(inFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), this fixed the issue.

Comment: That doesn't help for me unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `HttpPut()` again, but you still have the `FileStream` opened. Try disposing of the FileStream before you recursively call `HttpPut()` from within itself.

```
//This part is specific to the setup on an Expo we're at...
                            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)
                            {
                                string redirectUrl = resp.Headers.Location.ToString();

                                if (redirectUrl.Contains("vme-store"))
                                {

                                    redirectUrl = redirectUrl.Replace("vme-store", "10.230.0.11");
                                }
                                content.Dispose();
                                return await HttpPut(redirectUrl, inFilePath);
                        }
```

In addition, you probably would want to dispose of any other IDisposable objects like the http response to ensure that all resources are freed before you proceed deeper into the stack trace. This is one problem with recursion, that while you are using `Using` statements you not leaving their scope so they are not doing their job.

Comment: I should ofcourse have tried that before asking, but I tried it now by adding content.Dispose(); before the recursive call; that didn't help :/ Also, when running the code in our local testenvironment I never fire the recursive call

Comment: The stream should be open to get the request, also it is not a FileStream.

Comment: @Despertar: Quote: This is one problem with recursion, that while you are using Using statements you not leaving their scope so they are not doing their job.

That's usefull to know, thanks. But as I said, I never enter the if-statement firing the recursive call when running it in our local environment, and still I'm getting the same result

Comment: Can you verify if the problem occurs without recurrsion. Remove the inner call to `HttpPut()` and see if you can reproduce it. If you can't then atleast that gives a big clue as to where the problem lies. @Marco Look at this line `using (var content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(inFilePath, FileMode.Open)))` .

Comment: Commenting out the entire if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect || resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)-block gives the same result. And there's no redirection going on where I'm testing it now to begin with

Comment: That's great! Instead of adding the solution to your question, you can put it as an answer to your own question then mark it as the accepted answer. This will help people in the future find it quicker if they have a similar issue.

Comment: It's not really an answer to what I was asking though, I still have no idea why that didn't work :p