# Size limit on UploadFile of WebClient

Tags: c#, azure, webclient

I got into an issue while uploading a zip file to Azure for a webjob.

All goes well when the zip file size is less than 10MB, however when trying to upload larger files I get this exception:

> The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations

Stack:

> - at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
> - at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
> - at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBitsState.WriteBytes()
> - at System.Net.WebClient.UploadBits(WebRequest request, Stream readStream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 chunkSize, Byte[] header, Byte[] footer, CompletionDelegate uploadCompletionDelegate, CompletionDelegate downloadCompletionDelegate, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
> - at System.Net.WebClient.UploadFile(Uri address, String method, String fileName)

Here's my code:

```
var client = new MyWebClient
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(webSite.UserName, webSite.Password),                
};
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/zip");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={appFile}");

var response = client.UploadFile(uploadUri, "PUT", filePath);
```

where `MyWebClient` is an implementation of `WebClient` where I need to set the timeout:

```
private class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000;
        return w;
    }
}
```

Any idea on where the size restriction can be? I'm sure it's client side and not depending on .Net Framework as I tested with several of them.

***EDIT***
The solution was to force AllowWriteStreamBuffering to false by casting WebClient to HttpWebRequest:

```
            protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
            {
                WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
                w.Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000;
                var httpRequest = w as HttpWebRequest;
                if (httpRequest != null)
                {
                    httpRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
                }
                return w;
            }
```

Comment: Are you reusing the WebClient elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @Nasreddine I'm not using the client anywhere else

Comment: @ehsan-sajjad, this is not a duplicate question, please read the description and solution before marking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is documented in this blog entry http://vikeed.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/uploading-large-files-using-http-put-in.html which suggests adding the following;

```
 HttpWebRequest request = new ... 
 request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
```

An identical problem was posted here [C# HttpClient PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885990/c-sharp-httpclient-put) which indicates that using `AllowAutoRedirect = false` will cause this error.

You could try modifying your settings as suggested in these two similar posts and seeing if it corrects your fault.

Comment: It's the right answer, I updated my wrapper for WebClient to cast to HttpWebRequest and set AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false